# Коллекция set - перегрузка сравнения для своего класса

Tags: c++

Есть контейнер `set<>`, в него я помещаю объекты класса `Combination`. Для их сортировки перегружаю оператор `()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Combination {
public:
    char comb[3];
    bool operator()(const Combination left, const Combination right)
    {
        if (left.comb[0] < right.comb[0]) return true;
        else if (left.comb[0] > right.comb[0]) return false;
        else if (left.comb[1] < right.comb[1]) return true;
        else if (left.comb[1] > right.comb[1]) return false;
        else if (left.comb[2] < right.comb[2]) return true;
        else if (left.comb[2] > right.comb[2]) return false;
        // if there - combinations are equal
        else return false;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<Combination, Combination> comboSet, lastElems;

    /*next some logic*/

    return 0;
}
```

`cplusplus.com` сообщает, что:

> Binary predicate that, taking two values of the same type of those
>   contained in the set, returns true if the first argument goes before
>   the second argument in the strict weak ordering it defines, and false
>   otherwise.
>   [set::set constructors - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/)

Вот это, `false otherwise`, звучит двояко, так как `false` вернётся как в случае, если правый больше, так и в случае, если элементы равны.

Собственно, вопросы:

1. Как контейнер принимает решение, что элементы равны и один из них
   нужно выкинуть?
2. Правильно ли я пользуюсь контейнером set?

(*) критика приветствуется

Comment: все компараторы типа bool должны вернуть false при равенстве объектов, особенно это хорошо видно на примере сортировки (если вернуть true то будет падение).

Comment: @pavel нету падения, попробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, можно и так, но:

1. Вы зачем-то копируете в оператор значения; лучше передавать как константную ссылку.
2. Конечно, оператор может быть членом класса, но при этом ваш контейнер для проверки равенства будет создавать объекты `Combination` - а зачем это надо? Лучше создать отдельный функтор.

Если есть оператор "меньше", то равенство `a` и `b` можно проверить как 
`!(a < b) && !(b < a)` (ну, или любой эквивалентной записью - принцип, я думаю, понятен).

Я бы на вашем месте написал

```
struct CombinationLess
{
    bool operator()(const Combination& left, const Combination& right)
    { ...
```

и, соответственно, использовал `set<Combination, CombinationLess>`. Примерно так.

P.S. Спасибо @pavel - замученный женским днем :), совсем не сообразил, что вполне можно обойтись просто написанием оператора `<`.

```
bool operator<(const Combination& right) const
{
    if (comb[0] < right.comb[0]) return true;
    else if (comb[0] > right.comb[0]) return false;
    else if (comb[1] < right.comb[1]) return true;
    else if (comb[1] > right.comb[1]) return false;
    else if (comb[2] < right.comb[2]) return true;
    else if (comb[2] > right.comb[2]) return false;
    // if there - combinations are equal
    else return false;
}
```

и тогда достаточно объявления

```
set<Combination> comboSet;
```

будет создан корректный компаратор по умолчанию, использующий этот оператор...

Кстати, я не трогал тело вашего сравнения, но оно, как бы это выразиться... тоже из разряда "зачем просто, если можно сложно?" - но это уже к теме вопроса не относится.

Comment: а почему бы вообще не переопределить в классе оператор сравнения (<) и всё? Тогда сет можно создать просто set<Combination> и компаратор сам применится.

Comment: @pavel Да, конечно же, вы правы. Сбило с толку сложное решение ТС :)

Comment: я бы вообще по текущему шаблону использовал pair<char, pair<char,char>> :)  и всё встроено сразу будет)

Comment: @pavel умно, спасибо, запомню ;)

Comment: @pavel, если уж про `pair` заговорили, то нужно выбирать `std::tuple`, а не нагромождение из `pair`

Comment: CC @DimTeam. Смотрите комментарий выше.

Comment: @Harry спасибо за ответ. Вообще то, относится, так как я попросил немного критики) Не могли бы добавить в ответ, как лучше описать тело сравнения?

Comment: а про tuple спасибо) я и забыл про эту структурку

Comment: @DimTeam Ну... так, навскидку - `return strncmp(comb,right.comb,3) < 0`

Answer (score 5):

Чисто в образовательных целях, можно написать оператор `<` для класса:

```
#include <tuple>

class Combination {
public:
    char comb[3];
    bool operator<(const Combination& right)
    {
        return std::tie(comb[0], comb[1], comb[2])
            < std::tie(right.comb[0], right.comb[1], right.comb[2]);
    }
};
```

Но вообще, на мой взгляд, это как раз тот случай, когда класс и не нужен, а достаточно одного `tuple`:

```
using Combination = std::tuple<char, char, char>;
```

Что касается первого вопроса: в контейнере `set` используется отношение эквивалентности, два элемента считаются эквивалентными, если ни один не больше другого.

Comment: Ещё бы добавить `const` для оператора, и в силу публичности класса сделать его `struct`.